# How to access only spark logs in a yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm using spark with yarn in cluster mode and I wouldlike to retrieve only the logs concerning spark in order to use the history server. Is there a way to do that instead of copy pasting it from the big log files ?

Comment: `yarn application -list | grep "SPARK" | awk '{print $1}'` to get the applicationId of all spark applications

Comment: @Tiffany Hatsune Hi, can you please help me setting zeppelin on spark cluster mode using docker. I am stuck with this for a while. Followed few tutorial on internet but still unsuccessful.

Comment: Already asked a question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149472/running-zeppelin-on-spark-cluster-mode

Comment: Sorry I don't have any experience with Zeppelin :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can take logs of each task.
You need to go to the yarn UI (8088 port) and copy id of the task.
Then use command:

```
yarn logs --applicationId <TASK_ID>
```

For example:

```
yarn logs --applicationId application_1504771895665_0001
```

By this command you can see logs of each container that task used.

Comment: Is this command supposed to fetch the logs even after the job has finished or even failed/killed?