# Running zeppelin on spark cluster mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, docker, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

I am using this tutorial [spark cluster on yarn mode in docker container](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/install/spark_cluster_mode.html#spark-on-yarn-mode) to launch zeppelin in spark cluster in yarn mode. However I am stuck at step 4. I can't find conf/zeppelin-env.sh in my docker container to put further configuration. I tried putting these conf folder of zeppelin but yet now successful. Apart from that zeppelin notebook is also not running on localhost:9001.

I am very new to distributed system, it would be great if someone can help me start zeppelin on spark cluster in yarn mode.

Here is my docker-compose file to enable zeppelin talk with spark cluster.

```
version: '2'
services:
sparkmaster:
  build: .
  container_name: sparkmaster
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
  - "7077:7077" 
  - "8888:8888"
  - "8081:8081"
  - "8082:8082"
  - "5050:5050"
  - "5051:5051"
  - "4040:4040"
zeppelin:
  image: dylanmei/zeppelin
  container_name: zeppelin-notebook
env_file:
  - ./hadoop.env
environment:
  ZEPPELIN_PORT: 9001
  CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS: "hdfs://namenode:8020"
  HADOOP_CONF_DIR_fs_defaultFS: "hdfs://namenode:8020"
  SPARK_MASTER: "spark://spark-master:7077"
  MASTER: "yarn-client"
  SPARK_HOME: spark-master
  ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS: >-
    -Dspark.driver.memory=1g
    -Dspark.executor.memory=2g
ports:
  - 9001:9001
volumes:
  - ./data:/usr/zeppelin/data
  - ./notebooks:/usr/zeppelin/notebook
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the dockerfile you used to launch the standalone spark cluster.

- https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/scripts/docker/spark-cluster-managers/spark_standalone/Dockerfile

But there is no Zeppelin instance inside the container, so you have to use Zeppelin on your local machine.

Please [download](http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html) and use it.

Comment: I have used this dockerfile https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/scripts/docker/spark-cluster-managers/spark_yarn_cluster/Dockerfile 


Though this also doesn't have zeppelin, so I launched another container with zeppelin docker image, but unable to make zeppelin talk with spark cluster.

Comment: You have to merge them into one network, otherwise, can't connect each other. For example, you can make new docker-compose file include thoese dockerfiles.

Comment: Done that as well, I have added my docker-compose file. Above mentioned dockerfile and docker-compose are in the same folder. But this launches a single container only having zeppelin in that container.

Comment: Could you share your spark interpreter setting?

Comment: Unable to find it, docker ps gives me this:

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
1e8b6ea5e009        dylanmei/zeppelin   "bin/zeppelin.sh"   16 hours ago        Up 25 minutes       0.0.0.0:9001->9001/tcp   zeppelin-notebook

Comment: To use spark cluster in Zeppelin, you need to set proper URL for spark interpreter itself. Then, how did you setup the URL for the spark cluster?

Comment: We don't need to use dockerized Zeppelin, let's try binary in your local machine first to remove complexities.