# Connection from local machine installed Zeppelin to Docker Spark cluster

Tags: linux, docker, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to configure Spark interpreter on a local machine installed Zeppelin version 0.10.0 so that I can run scripts on a Spark cluster created also local on Docker. I am using docker-compose.yml from https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark and Spark version 3.1.2.
 After docker compose-up, I can see in the browser spark-master on localhost:8080 and History Server on localhost:18081. After reading the ID of the spark-master container, I can also run shell and spark-shell on it (docker exec -it xxxxxxxxxxxx /bin/bash). As host OS I am using Ubuntu 20.04, the spark.master in Zeppelin is set now to spark://localhost:7077, zeppelin.server.port in zeppelin-site.xml to 8070.
There is a lot of information about connecting a container running Zeppelin or running both Spark and Zeppelin in the same container but unfortunately I also use that Zeppelin to connect to the Hive via jdbc on VirtualBox Hortonworks cluster like in one of my previous posts and I wouldn't want to change that configuration now due to hardware resources. In one of the posts ([Running zeppelin on spark cluster mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149472/running-zeppelin-on-spark-cluster-mode)) I saw that such a connection is possible, unfortunately all attempts end with the "Fail to open SparkInterpreter" message. 
I would be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `spark.master` in Zeppelin to point to the spark master in the docker container not the local machine. Hence `spark://localhost:7077` won't work.

The port `7077` is fine because that is the port specified in the docker-compose [file](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark#using-docker-compose) you are using. To get the IP address of the docker container you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20686101/19261326) answer. Since I suppose your container is named `spark-master` you can try the following:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' spark-master
```

Then specify this as the `spark.master` in Zeppelin: `spark://docker-ip:7077`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it did not solve the problem. spark-master ip is obviously '172.21.0.2' but while browsing through the logs, I noticed a message "requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem"

Comment: The error is probably caused by running a different Spark version in the cluster then the one used for Spark submit. [Supported Interpreters list](https://zeppelin.apache.org/supported_interpreters.html) does not include version 10.0, but this Zeppelin previously worked fine with Spark 3.1.3 with SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark, at the moment there is no value there.

Comment: The final solution is to set spark.master to spark://172.18.0.2:7077 (in my case) as suggested by @viggnah and downgrade the Spark version to 2.4.5-hadoop2.7 in bde2020 docker-compose file. It is the same version as pre-installed in Zeppelin 10.0 (the pre-installed version can be checked by setting spark.master to local[*] in Interpreters/spark and run `val sparkver = sc.version` in the notebook).